# I can't add a new line to c++ string

Tags: c++, newline, escaping

How do you add a new line to a c++ string? I'm trying to read a file but when I try to append '\n' it doesn't work.

```
std::string m_strFileData;
while( DataBegin != DataEnd ) {
    m_strFileData += *DataBegin;
    m_strFileData += '\n';
    DataBegin++;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Does your computer melt? Does your dog drink all your beer? What?

Comment: If you are debugging using Visual Studio you are probably not seeing it correctly in the debugger.

Comment: @dalle - good point, use Text Visualizer to see the WYSIWYG version

Comment: @dreamlax I have clearly said appending \n doesnt work and @dalle I need the new lines for my interpreter on the next step and it needs new lines and that doesnt work.

Comment: What you're saying is that if you took your car to a mechanic and just said "I want to drive the car but it doesn't work", you would expect them to know how to fix it? Describe your problem in more detail. Through what observations have you determined your code to be faulty? What data types are `DataBegin` and `DataEnd`. How are you inspecting/displaying the string (if it is displayed in a GUI element, does the element support multiple lines)? We can't read your mind. Saying "it doesn't work" is as useful as tits on bull.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a lot of lines to process, using `stringstream` could be more efficient.

```
ostringstream lines;

lines << "Line 1" << endl;
lines << "Line 2" << endl;

cout << lines.str();   // .str() is a string
```

Output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about the late answer, but I had a similar problem until I realised that the Visual Studio 2010 `char*` visualiser ignores `\r` and `\n` characters. They are completely ommitted from it.

Note: By visualiser I mean what you see when you hover over a `char*` (or `string`).

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but perhaps you should change the character to a string:

```
 m_strFileData += '\n';
```

to be this:

```
 m_strFileData += "\n";
```

Comment: The `+=` operator supports both ways.

Answer (score 1):

This would append a newline after each character, or string depending on what type DataBegin actually is. Your problem does not lie in you given code example. It would be more useful if you give your expected and actual results, and the datatypes of the variables use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(filename);
std::string entireString = "";
std::string line;

while (getline(inFile,line))
{
   entireString.append(line);
   entireString.append("\n");
}
```