# Add a new line using String^ in C++

Tags: string, visual-c++, newline, line-breaks, managed-c++

I'm writing a program where you can enter text and output a text file with that text.

I have this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    String^ fileName = "registry.txt";
    String^ out;

    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);

    out = "hi";
    out = out + "\n how you doing?";

    sw->WriteLine(out);

    sw->Close();
}
```

Basically I want this:

```
hi
how you doing?
```

But what I get is this:

```
hi how you doing?
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: That's managed C++. Please use the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Is this C++-CLI? If so, please tag it as so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't add a new line to c++ string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128077/i-cant-add-a-new-line-to-c-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use static data member `Environment::NewLine`

For example

```
out = out + Environment::NewLine + " how you doing?";
```

Or you can explicitly specfy escape control symbol '\r' along with '\n' used in Windows to separate lines.

```
out = out + "\r\n how you doing?";
```

Here is an example of using the both methods

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String ^fileName( "Data.txt" );
    String^ out;

    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter( fileName );

    out = "hi";
    out = out + "\r\n how you doing?";

    sw->WriteLine(out);

    out = "hi";
    out = out + Environment::NewLine + " how you doing?";

    sw->WriteLine(out);

    sw->Close();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
hi
 how you doing?
hi
 how you doing?
```